# Responsive css not working on small devices only

Tags: css, responsive-design, styles, media-queries, postcss

I want the following css to work only on small devices (mobile) but is working on mobile and on tablet as well. How can I make it work only on mobile?

```
@media (max-width: 980px) {
  h2 {
    font-size: 3em;
  }

  p {
    font-size: 2.3em;
    line-height: 1.7em;
  }

  button {
    width: 400px;
    height: 80px;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}
```

According to [postcss](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-custom-media), if I do `@media (max-width: 30em)` it will work only on small devices. But it doesn't work and I don't know why.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How wide is your small device? you should be able to simply modify the max-width value to the width of that device. Ex: an iphoneX is 375px wide so you can set @media (max-width: 376) to set styles to only apply on devices with a width smaller than 375.

Comment: Thanks! @MichaelSorensen I tried `max-width: 376px` and other values but the only values that work are the ones greater than 980px (even 979 doesn't work on small devices, I'm trying it on a iphone 6s) I don't know why this is happening

Answer (score 3):

With CSS units, `em`s are a relative size based on the inherited `font-size`. Since you're a beginnner, I'd stick with `px` values for now. Like @MichaelSorensen said, set a lower value. With the media query you posted, you're saying "all windows with a `max-width` of `980px` should apply these values". Want it to be only to small devices? Set a lower value.

[Here are some standard device widths [CSS Tricks]](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

It's worth mentioning that "mobile first" is a concept you'll see a lot. Basically, you start with media queries that apply to all devices then start adding media query breakpoints that apply to a certain size going *up*. Here is an oversimplified example.

```
/* this applies to .my-class no matter what size until you override */
.my-class {
    background-color: #f00; /* red */
}

/* this applies starting at 768px, many tablets */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .my-class {
        background-color: #0f0 /* green */
    }
}

/* this applies starting at 1200px, many larger devices */
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .my-class {
        background-color: #00f /* blue */
    }
}
```

Like I said, this is oversimplified. But if you're reading blog posts about media queries and not getting it, hopefully this helps.

Comment: You could also stick to rems. ems will stack up making them a bit more complicated to handle. For example, an element with font-size defined at 3em with a child element that also defines font-size at 3em will end up being 9em. From my experience sticking to rem is safest as well. Might want to consider using that in the future! (not that this is currently affecting the outcome).

Comment: Sure, `rem`s are easier to deal with than `em`s. But if I'm starting out and I want to really understand what's happening, I'd stick with `px` and set a bookmark in my brain to come back to the rest the units.

Comment: Agreed, was hoping to highlight the difference for him since (in my experience) rems (compared to ems) tend to be used more often anyways. Don't disagree with your point on px at all.

Answer (score 1):

While @mccambridge's answer is correct. I think @Liz Parody might be having a different issue. I taught some students and many of them struggled with Media Queries because there are a few easy things to forget.

1. Remember that Media Queries function similar to if statements. In that multiple queries can resolve true. Look at the picture below as an example.

[image]

2. CSS renders from the top down so in the below example if you kept the same 200px screen a red box with blue text would render as the last media query will over-write the previous. You can see this in action in your browser's dev tools:

[image]

But, you can re-order them and the result will change. This can get especially complicated with multiple style sheets. There are multiple valid strategies to cope with this I just recommend picking one and sticking with it making sure your entire team is on the same page.